# Bathroom Tile Removal - Underlayment and membrane coming up

Tags: bathroom, tile, removal, underlayment

I'm removing all the tile in a bathroom. While removing though, I believe it's the underlayment is coming up with some of the tiles.  I was wondering what are the reprecussions of this.

Picture: [image]

1. Does this matter? Can I still lay tile on top of this even though it's coming up?
2. Can I repair the underlayment? If so, how?

A lot of the articles online for #2 are for water damage. This isn't the case for me.

Thanks,
Justin W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tile over a solid surface. Needless to say, this stuff doesn't count, so you'll need to remove it. With a wooden subfloor, the preferred tile base is cementboard. Screw it down, mortar the seams, and go to town with your tiles.